# LINQ check if exists, but without equal to any value

Tags: c#, linq

I try to get datas from database. I need to get first product's image url ordered by the lowest position. Action is running on Index view where I have 20 records per page. Code to get image url with first position:

```
var firstImage = productImageRepository.Get().Where(i => i.ProductId == productId).OrderBy(i => i.Position).First();
```

In my database only products with id 1-7 have images. When the loop is on product with id 8 and higher, I'm getting and error:

[image]

Is there possibility to check if this product's image exists in database? I know I can equal it to some value and check it like if (firstImage != null), but I don't know how to do this without equal position to any value.

Comment: Please post your code as test and not as a screenshot

Comment: Use `FirstOrDefault` or `Any` if you explicitly only want to check if there are any elements returned in the IQueryable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `FirstOrDefault()`, it is just like `First()` except that if no element match the specified condition than it returns the default value of the underlying type of generic collection.

You can then check if the value is defined which tells you if any items exist in the database, in your case `FirstOrDefault()` will return `null` if no images exist in the database.

You can also use `Any()` with `First()` as well

My solution would be

```
var images = productImageRepository.Get().Where(i => i.ProductId == productId).OrderBy(i => i.Position);
if (images.Any()) {
    // could just use First() here now if you wanted 
    // as Any() confirms there is values defined
    return Json(images.FirstOrDefault());
} else {
   // throw a error or something. 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to replace `First()` with `FirstOrDefault()`. If there are no items in the collection, `FirstOrDefault()` will return the type's default value. So you cold then have a bool which indicates if the first found element has an image (assuming the default value of firstImage is `null`, otherwise retrievable by `default(<Type of firstImage here>)`): `bool imageExists = (firstImage != null);`